# Help identifying a SOP-18 IC (labels removed) by reverse engineered circuit

Tags: integrated-circuit, identification, reverse-engineering

I have a SOP-18 IC (0.65mm pin pitch) which I need to identify. It seems the vendor removed the labels on top of the IC, so I need your help.

The IC is usually connected to a bunch of LEDs and two pins are connected to an epoxy blob (I guess a MCU). I assume the IC is some kind of shift register or LED driver, but I would like to know which one exactly. Based on the number of pins and location of the GND and VCC pin I could also assume it's a PIC MCU, but just for controlling LEDs, that would be an overkill imho...

On the bottom side of the IC, there are some codes: "T6AL7CFF0074-2" and "VO8"

Attached I have pictures of the IC top and a schematic how to IC is connected on the PCB. Under the IC on the PCB there was the code "8A21" printed on the silkscreen.

I hope you can help me to identify this part.

[image: Reverse engineered circuit]
[image: Photo of the IC]

Comment: Did you have a chance to probe the signals from the nodes labeled "MCU" before desoldering?

Comment: Please double check pin 4 and 5 and add the expected voltage of Vcc and double check the value of the cap (hard to read; 10µF?).

Comment: @try-catch-finally I presume the SMD component was labeled 104, and might just be a pull-down resistor (that would make more sense on a digital serial line)

Comment: I analyzed the communication between MCU and the IC in the meantime. I could find out that Pin 16 might be some kind of enable pin, because LEDs are only on, when this pin is low. Pin 13 is however getting the data in how many LEDs should light. Every time this pin gets a low (within a short time frame), another LED will be enabled, if there is no more "low" on this pin, the IC is disabling one LED after another (every 450ms). Generally speaking LEDs are toggled every 450ms.

Answer (score 2):

2 pins coming from an MCU sounds like a serial link; since the IC has 10 parallel outputs, this smells like a serial to parallel shift register.

The 10kΩ resistor is probably used to set the current that the IC allows each LED to sink into Pin 1–3, 6–10, 17–18.

This sounds like one of the relatively popular LED drivers out there; for example, starchip [SCT2016](https://www.tme.eu/en/details/sct2016ctsg/led-drivers/starchips-technology/), though that has 16 output channels.

The fact that there's no marking on the package might mean you simply can't buy that chip: might be a one-off run in some old wafer fab.

If the marking was actually scraped off: this surely hasn't happened because someone tried to hide trade secrets from their competitors (this LED driver's job is so obvious that this wouldn't help, at all), but probably because these are counterfeits of some large IC manufacturer's design and they couldn't have imported the device with the counterfeits claiming they were the real deal.

I tried to look through the LED drivers over at octoparts.com and filtered for ICs with 18 pins – [link](https://octopart.com/search?&category_ids=5053&q=&specs2.24.values=18&start=0) – but none of these even remotely have a comparable pinout to yours. Since Octopart only list major distributor inventory (ie. none of the "small chinese company with 2 engineers that runs wafers on the cheapest technology that written-off wafer fabs offer"), it's pretty unlikely you'll be able to find a chip that's 100% compatible to yours.

Comment: Thanks for your great answer. But I'm really not sure if this is a "dumb" shift register, in fact I found out that this IC is turning on and off the LEDs step by step every ~450ms. If there are more pulses on Pin 13, the IC is "enabling more outputs" if there are no more pulses on Pin 13 the IC is disabling LED after LED every 450ms. Seems like a counter with "auto-reverse"... (see also my new comment above)

Answer (score 1):

This looks to me like a Microchip PIC16F microcontroller (or something similar). Check out one of the datasheets here: [Datasheet](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/devicedoc/30430c.pdf)

The power and ground are right. Pin 16 (CLKIN) is a clock input, and I'll bet it's being fed the clock from the other mcu. The pin 15 (CLKOUT) is disconnected (which is how it should be when the controller is being fed an external clock source)

As to which microcontroller exactly? You might be able to hook it up to a icsp programmer, but I don't really know.